Understanding why the number of tic-tac-toe games is not $2^9$.
I understand that a rough estimate for the number of games is $9!$. That is, there are 9 moves for the first move then 8 moves for the second, and so on.
But surely you could say that since there are $9$ squares, each being either an X or an O, there are $2^9$ possible games.
These numbers are very far apart, and I know I am wrong. But I want to know why I am incorrect.
EDIT: Basically, I am mixing up the number of possible end states and the number of possible games. The number of end states is small, but the number of games is rather large. That is, for a particular end game we can have multiple games that end in that end game. This is explained better in the answers.

Well, you need to have $5$ $X's$ and $4$ $O's$, for example...

Both numbers describe different scenarios (though one of them is still incorrect). Both assume that a game only ends when all squares are occupied, not when the game is won.
How many possible games are there?
Here, the order is important. The first line can be filled like xox in two different ways: X starts by either choosing the left or the right square, and chooses the other square on their second turn. That's two different games, though the playing fields look the same.
The number of games is indeed $9!$.
How many end states of the game are there?
Here, the order in which the x and os have been placed doesn't matter, only their position does. Naively, one could assume that this number is $2^9$ (every square is either x or o). But this is wrong because if x starts, then 5 squares are x and four are o. So the correct number of end states is the number of ways to distribute five xs to nine squares (the rest are automatically o). That number is $\binom{9}{5}$. Or equivalently, $\binom{9}{4}$ (the number of ways to distribute four os).

Makes sense. I was assuming that xox can only be achieved in one way. When we take into account order the number is definitely larger than $2^9$

I think I am mixing up the number of end states and how many possible games there are. We could arrive at a particular end state in a number of different ways. Hence the number of possible games is very large. Or larger than the number of end states.

A game might end with empty squares, something might win on the fifth move (if their opponent was very weak).

@badjohn I mentioned in my answer that I'm assuming the game ends once all squares are occupied. The calculation is more complex if we assume it ends after a win.

@Vercassivelaunos On rereading, I see that.

The reason your estimate of $2^9$ is false is because the players take ordered turns; that is, there can be at most five O's on the final board, but your estimate includes the final board containing nine O's, as well as the final board containing nine X's and everything in between. In addition, two games ending with the same board may not be the same game, since turns are ordered.
Your estimate of $9!$ is better, and indeed is correct if we want to fill the entire board regardless of a winner (and we assume that the same player always goes first).  However, in actual tic-tac-toe, after one player gets three in a row the game ends, meaning that some games end with blank squares and some are unreachable. It takes much more work to find the actual number, and I would recommend this website for learning about that.
As stated on that website, the actual number of possible tic-tac-toe games is $255168$.
Hope this helps!

From your explanation (first paragraph) it would seem that $2^9$ is an over count. Even though it is nowhere near the 9! figure. I'm really sorry I still don't understand why I am wrong (even though I know I am wrong)

@HMPtwo Think of it this way: the $2^9$ estimate counts all possible end boards with any number of X's and O's (as long as they fill the whole board). In an actual tic-tac-toe game, you couldn't place nine X's in a row, or nine O's in a row, or in fact anything besides five X's and four O's. So it is not a choice between an X and an O in every box, but a choice of where to place a predetermined symbol on every turn.
